# java excel api- how to determine last row when reading a spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I cant see any mention of how to check if current cell is last row in a spreadsheet in java excel api docs...

When I use code and try to fetch data in next row (after the last row) I get an error-

I can trap this error and hence capture the scenario of having surpassed the last row, however I would like to know if there is some way of directly identifying if a row is the last row in excel sheet, when using java excel api?

For reference, the code that causes this error is given below -- (The exact line that causes the error is the 3rd line in code below)--

```
//  now go to next value of url in the spreadsheet...
rownum++;
datacell=sheet.getCell((columnread-1), rownum );
```

For reference, the error I get is --

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
 at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
 at com.arvind.dataentry.Dataentry.process_file(Dataentry.java:245)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the last row with `getRows()`. It returns the number of rows in the current sheet. With this information you can identify if a given row is the last in a sheet.

See also: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Sheet.html#getRows()

Comment: `code`Workbook workBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("../xls/data/test.xls"));
int sheetNumberOfRows = workBook.getSheet(0).getRows();
int sheetNumberOfColumns = workBook.getSheet(0).getColumns();
System.out.println(sheetNumberOfColumns + "--" + sheetNumberOfRows);`code`